# Angular 2.1 HTTP client does it support onProgress

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

First of all - a similar question was asked before Angular 2 was released and the answer was basically no. Some strange looking workarounds were suggested but they didn't work when I tried them. I was hoping that this feature had been added to the release

I am writing a web application with Angular 2 in typescript and I want to upload one or more images while showing progress. This is simple enough to do with raw XmlHttpRequest but I would have thought it possible using the Angular 2 HTTP wrapper. The documentation for Angular2 HTTP says it uses XmlHttpRequest as the back end so perhaps there is a way to access the raw request?

Comment: At the moment, HTTP support doesn’t support the ability to follow the progress of both downloading and uploading.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular >= 4.3**

```
https://angular.io/guide/http
```

Listening to progress events

Sometimes applications need to transfer large amounts of data, and those transfers can take time. It's a good user experience practice to provide feedback on the progress of such transfers; for example, uploading files—and @angular/common/http supports this.

To make a request with progress events enabled, first create an instance of HttpRequest with the special reportProgress option set:

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
  reportProgress: true,
});
```

This option enables tracking of progress events. Remember, every progress event triggers change detection, so only turn them on if you intend to actually update the UI on each event.

Next, make the request through the request() method of HttpClient. The result will be an Observable of events, just like with interceptors:

```
http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
  // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
  // Look for upload progress events.
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
    const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
  } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
  }
});
```